# scoring straight (or run) in Cribbage

Tags: cribbage

In Cribbage, what is the scoring rule in this example?

- Player 1 plays a 4.
- Player 2 plays a 3.
- Player 3 plays a 5. (claims 3 points for 4,3,5 run)
- Player 4 plays a 6. (now 4 more points for 4,3,5,6 run)
- Player 1 plays a second 4 (**here the debate)**

He claims that he should get another 4 points (for 3,5,6,4) indicating by pointing at each card *in reverse of the sequence of play* (counterclockwise) 6,3,5,4 ending with his second 4).

I claim that he can't count the second run of four cards because they were not in the sequence of play (clockwise).

Who is right?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here; why is "3564" problematic, but "435" and "4356" are acceptable? None of those are in order, so I don't see how "the sequence of play" comes into question.

Answer (score 6):

From the [American Cribbage Congress Rules of Cribbage](http://www.cribbage.org/NewSite/rules/rule1.asp):

> **straight (or run), single:** Sequence of three or more consecutive cards in any order during the play of the cards; for example, 3-5-6-7-4 (counts three when the 7 is played and counts five when the 4 is played)

When the second 4 is played by Player 1 the last 4 cards played are:

3, 5, 6, 4

This set of 4 consecutive cards clearly meets the definition above of:

> ... Sequence of three or more consecutive cards in any order during the play of the cards ....

Player 1 is entitled to score 4 for this **run**.

In regards to your claim above that:

> ... he can't count the second run of four cards because they were not in the sequence of play (clockwise).

Nowhere in the Rules is there a necessity to identify the qualifying cards for a score in a specified order. Your claim otherwise is entirely bogus.

The sequence counts solely by virtue of the required cards, having been played, meeting the criterion of being "*Sequence of three or more consecutive cards in any order*".  Any such identification of qualifying cards is purely informative, and instructive, to assist beginners in learning the game.